# Symfony2 / Doctrine Relationship Mapping

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, entity-relationship

i'm building my first application with the syfmony2 framework. 
Now i stick a little bit on how to get data from my Database.

First here a my tables (only important fields)

**# customer**

customer_id | INT | AI | PK

**# article**

article_id | INT | AI | PK

number | VARCHAR

**# customer_article** (Both fields build the PK)

customer_id | INT | PK

article_id | INT | PK

Now i want to perform a simply query like this:

```
SELECT 
   ca.article_id, a.number 
FROM 
   customer_article AS ca
LEFT JOIN 
   article AS a ON a.article_id = ca.article_id
WHERE 
   ca.customer_id = {customer_id}
```

As far as i understand the documentation the best way is to 
make a Relationship Mapping in my entity php files.

Customer.php

Article.php

CustomerArticle.php

But i'm confused what to do and in which direction.
(http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html)

In My opinion this must be the right relationship

Customer to CustomerArticle is a One-To-Many (Unidirectional) Relationship

CustomerArticle to Customer is a Many-To-One (Unidirectional) Relationship

Article to CustomerArticle is a One-To-Many (Unidirectional) Relationship

CustomerArticle to Article is a Many-To-One (Unidirectional) Relationship

Is it right at this point?

And now is it neccessary to make this (4) Relationships Mapping in every
Entity file? Or do i only need to do it one way e.g.
Customer to CustomerArticle (One-To-Many - Unidirectional) and 
Article to CustomerArticle (One-To-Many  - Unidirectional)

unfortunately the "One-To-May, Unidirectional" is the only one with no
proper example on the doctrine reference-page.

They write:
"From Doctrine’s point of view, it is simply mapped as a unidirectional many-to-many whereby a unique constraint on one of the join columns enforces the one-to-many cardinality"

Does this mean i only have to do the mapping like on the "unidirectional many-to-many" section of the page?

Sorry about the many questions.

I read a lot in the documentations but i can't answer these questions for myself.

Thanks for any help.

**Update 26.04.2013**

Unfortunately i can't get it work even with the help from Lighthart and reading the Doctrine documentation.

I think it's helpfull to give you more details about my tables and code. Maybe someone can give me the essential answer so i finaly understand the concept behind it.

**My Tables with some example Entries**

```
Table: customer (PK: customer_id)
+-------------+--------+----------+-------------------+------+-----------+
| customer_id | number | password | email             | salt | is_active |
+-------------+--------+----------+-------------------+------+-----------+
| 1           | CU0001 | 43t9wef  | test@example.com  | test | 1         |
| 2           | CU0002 | 32rk329  | test2@example.com | test | 1         |
+-------------+--------+----------+-------------------+------+-----------+

Table: article (PK: article_id)
+-------------+---------+
| article_id  | number  |
+-------------+---------+
| 1           | TEST-01 |
| 2           | TEST-02 |
| 3           | TEST-03 |
| 4           | TEST-04 |
| 5           | TEST-05 |
+-------------+---------+
```

**What i have done since my first Posting?**

- Delete the CustomerArticle.php
- Delete the customer_article table
- Add a ManyToMany Relationship to the Customer (And Article) Entity

**This is how the entity files look like at this moment (without methods)**

Customer.php

```
<?php
namespace Test\ExampleBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer")
 */
class Customer implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $customer_id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="customers")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="customer_article",
 *  joinColumns={ @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="customer_id" ) }
 * )
 */
private $articles;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false, unique=true)
 */
protected $number;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected  $salt;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 *
 */
protected  $isActive;

// ... methods
}
```

Article.php

```
<?php
namespace Test\ExampleBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 */
class Article
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $article_id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Customer", mappedBy="articles")
 */
private $customers;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false, unique=true)
 */
protected $number;

// ... methods
}
```

When i try to execute:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get the following Message

```
[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
Column name `id` referenced for relation from    Test\ExampleBundleBundle\Entity\Customer towards Test\ExampleBundleBundle\Entity\Article does not exist.
```

I don't know why doctrine wants to use a column name "id". I read something about this error and add the "JoinColumns"-Code but it didn't help.

**What is my goal?**

I import data from some csv-files into the tables:
"customer", "article" and also into the currently not exist table "customer_article".

In my application every customer has a few articles referenced to him. 
So the Table will looks like this

```
customer_article
+-------------+------------+
| customer_id | article_id |
+-------------+------------+
| 1           | 1          |
| 1           | 2          |
| 1           | 5          |
| 2           | 2          |
| 2           | 5          |
+-------------+------------+
```

It's not a Shop or something like this. It's quite difficult to explain so first it's only neccessary to know that every customer has a undefined quantity of associated articles.

Now i must be able to get all articles assosiated with one customer using tthe customer_id. (Look at my example sql statement in the starting post above)

I hope you can help me.

Thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really looks like a bidirectional many to many with customer and article.  The entities you would build are Customer.php and Article.php, and you would specify a many-to-many in those files via annotation, or in doctrine.orm.yml depending on your preference.

Doctrine will make the intermediate table for you (customer_article) and manage it.

You would use DQL:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT a FROM Article a JOIN a.customer c");
$users = $query->getResult();
```

Then you would process articles as entities, and call article.getCustomer() for a list of customers associated with an article.

This is a fundamentally different paradigm than SQL and will take some getting used to.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
I'm a bit confused does this mean i have to delete my CustomerArticle Entity and with it the created table?

You wrote 
"Doctrine will make the intermediate table for you (customer_article) and manage it."

Does this mean the fact that i make a many-to-many annotation in
Customer.php and Article.php ensures that Doctrine will create a
table "customer_article" without having it specified in CustomerArticle.php?


As far as i understand your DQL-Example i can also do it vice versa to get
all articles associated with an user?

It's realy a different approach - thank you

Comment: If, AND ONLY IF, you have other properties associated with the many-to-many join you will need to manually specify the join table.  Otherwise, you do not need it as an entity.  If there are no other fields besides the foreign keys, you should delete it and let doctrine handle that for you.  And you are right about the inverse query `$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customer c JOIN c.article a");` being necessary to get a list of customers .

Comment: I can't get it work. I extend my first post maybe it helps to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is bad.  You specify jointable but don't specify the inverse join column.  Try:

```
 /**
  * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Article")
  * @JoinTable(name="customer_article",
  *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Customer_id", referencedColumnName="cusomter_id")},
  *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Article_id", referencedColumnName="article_id")}
  *      )
  */
```

As an aside, mapping your primary keys to something other than 'id' is somewhat unusual.

Comment: This works well, thank you! Currently I don't fully understand why to use "inverseJoinColumns" (because it's missing also in the documentation of many-to-many bidirectional) but it's a keyword I can search to get more information about it. One Question left: In your "ManyToMany" Notation the inversedBy="customers" is missing. The Doctrine Doku says "The owning side of a bidirectional relationship must refer to its inverse side by use of the inversedBy attribute" Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: InversedBy is used for oneToMany or ManytoOne.  In those cases, the field it stored on the 'many' side in the database.  The InversedBy allows you to specify what you want the column named if you don't liked the default (similar to the JoinColumns and InverseJoinColumns in ManytoMany)